# Java Print MySQL Table Using MetaData

Tags: java, mysql, printing, metadata

How would I modify this so that it uses meta data to print the table?

```
public String formatStudentList() throws SQLException 
{ 
    String result = String.format("%-15s %-25s %-25s", "Student ID", "Student Name", "Degree    
      Scheme\n" + String.format("%-15s %-25s %-25s\n", "**********", "" +  
      "********************", "****************************")); 

    int count = 0; 
    try 
    { 
         conn = SimpleDataSource.getConnection(); 
         prepStat = conn.prepareStatement("SELECT * FROM student");
         ResultSet print = prepStat.executeQuery(); 

         while (print.next()) 
         { 
            String id = print.getString("studentId");
            String name = print.getString("studentName"); 
            String degree = print.getString("degreeScheme"); 
            result += String.format("%-15s %-25s %-25s\n", id, name, degree); 
            count++; 
         }

        if (result == null) 
        { 
            result = "No Students Were Found In Database\n";
        } 
        else 
        { 
            result += "\nTotal Number Of Student = " + count; 
        } 
        } catch (SQLException ex) 
        { 
             result = "Error Occurred: " + ex.getMessage(); 
        } finally 
        { 
             conn.close(); 
        } 
        return result; 
}
```

It does what I want perfectly, but using the meta data there is a way that it does the table spacing and headers automatically. Could anyone help me change this?

Answer (score 0):

From your `SimpleDataSource.getConnection()` you can call `getMetaData()` to get the `DatabaseMetaData getMetaData()`.

and from there you can call `getColumns`

see [javadocs](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/sql/DatabaseMetaData.html#getColumns%28java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String%29)

Answer (score 0):

MetaData is not a report that contains spacing formats for print or display purpose.

As per [ResultSetMetaData](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/sql/ResultSetMetaData.html) documentation:

> An object that can be used to get information about the types and properties of the columns in a `ResultSet` object.

It is clear that it contain's no specific information on how it has to be used for display or printing.

Your way of solution combined into a `result` string for presentation is not good.
It would always be a good practice to *encapsulate* the data read from ResultSet to form a Data Object. In your case it can be a `StudentDegreeScheme` object.

Create a class with necessary getter and setters and fill them from reading the ResultSet and return the `student...` object to the caller.

Caller should then use the same object to display or print after formatting using, for example, any HTML layout.

Hope you got the point.

Comment: What the system is a database for university task. And it has multiple tables and for the student table, when the user selects to print all student list it does the code above.

But i need to alter this so it implements the use of resultsetMetaData. And im not sure on how i would do this.

Comment: Your way of doing it is very RAW. At learning level, that is OK to gain some practice. To make it fairly tabulated, you need to find max length of each value in a column and based on that you need to set the `format` string.

Comment: This what i want to do, but not sure on how id do it. Thanks